# How to get access token for Unit Testing in .Net

Tags: moq, xunit

I require an access token to test methods in a service. I tried to hardcode the access token and it is working well. If I run the application after some time all test cases get failed. I believe it's because the access token gets expired. How can I generate access tokens without hardcoding?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I'm also looking for it. Need to update validity time of a hard-coded access token.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the way I used in my work.

First portion inject configuration and second is for getting access token. Hope so it will help you.

```
 public class TestConfigurationManager
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public TestConfigurationManager()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            if (_config == null)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"testsettings.json", optional: false);
                _config = builder.Build();
            }

            return _config;
        }
    }
}

[Fact(DisplayName = "GetAccessToken")]
    public async Task GetAccessToken()
    {
        var _configuration = new TestConfigurationManager().Configuration;
        var _httpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandler.Object);

        TokenRequest tokenRequest = new TokenRequest();
        _configuration.GetSection(AppSetting.Accounting.Token).Bind(tokenRequest);
        string baseAddress = $"{_configuration[AppSetting.Accounting.TokenURL]}"; ;

        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type", tokenRequest.GrantType},
                {"username", tokenRequest.UserName},
                {"password", tokenRequest.Password},
                {"key", tokenRequest.Key}
            };
        httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new System.Uri(_configuration[AppSetting.Accounting.BaseUrl])
        };
        HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
        var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(jsonContent);
        Assert.NotNull(tok?.AccessToken);
    }
```